# Como pasar datos de ventana modal a input con vuejs y axios?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, vue.js, axios

Quisiera saber si me puede apoyar, tengo este codigo html, estoy intentando pasar datos de una ventana modal a vuej. El problema es que el valor se pasa al input, pero no se por que, solo da un parpadeo y desaparece, quisiera saber si pueden apoyarme con esto, soy nuevo en el desarrollo de appweb, pero quiero hacer algo mas o menos desde el principio.

```
<div class="row" id="create_factura">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="nit">Nit</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nit" class="form-control" v-model="cnit">
            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Llenar Detalle</button>

  <!-- Modal Usuario -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

        <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <td>Nit</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="(cliente, index) in clientes">
                <td>@{{cliente.nit}}</td>
                <td>@{{cliente.nombre}}</td>
                <td><a href="" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="verCliente(index)">Seleccionar</a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y tengo este codigo de vuejs

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/';
var urlClientes = url + 'clientes';
new Vue({
  el: '#create_factura',
  created: function(){
    this.getClientes();
  },
  data: {
    clientes: [],
    cli: [{nit: ''}],
    cnit: ''
  },
  methods:
  {
    getClientes(){
      axios.get(urlClientes).then(response => {
        this.clientes = response.data
      });
    },
    verCliente(index){
      this.cnit = this.clientes[index].nombre;
      return this.cnit
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: ¿Para qué usas `return this.cnit` en el método verCliente() ?

Comment: Solo lo coloqué como prueba, para saber si me traia el dato, de hecho tenía un console.log(this.cnit)

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que se esté actualizando la página cuando haces el click en "Seleccionar", intenta cambiar el llamado a VerCliente:

```
v-on:click="verCliente(index)"
```

por

```
v-on:click.prevent="verCliente(index)"
```